# Java Slick2D Texture Issue

Tags: java, image, textures, slick2d

I was working on my game today and I found that the top of my trees have a weird texture problem where they overlap each other with a black box. It is only the top of the trees and the tops are split up into 9 blocks all with their own image. The 9 images are transparent, each is 32x32, and I've tried it a bunch of different ways with no luck. Does anyone know what the problem with the texture is? This isn't a generation question but an OpenGL/Slick2D question about textures. Here's a screenshot of the problem: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGTGA.jpg)

[image]

EDIT: Here's a piece of the rendering code.

```
for (int x = (int) (World.instance.camera.getX() / Block.WIDTH); x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = (int) (World.instance.camera.getY() / Block.HEIGHT); y < height; y++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (blocks[x][y] != Block.AIR.getId())
                {
                    g.drawImage(textureCache.get(blocks[x][y]), x * Block.WIDTH, y * Block.HEIGHT);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to know what you're doing wrong if we can't see your code.  Is there any chance you can post the relevant section of it here?

Comment: There isn't any code to post it's just g.drawImage(treeTop, x, y);

Comment: Well, I'd kind of like to play around and try to find out what's happening before I post an answer.  If you're only able to post one line of code, it makes it extremely difficult for me to do that.  I understand if you don't want to show the code of your game; but just the relevant section would be helpful.  Failing that, you could check out http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=25100.0 - your problem may be the issue that it deals with.

Comment: I posted an edit so you can view it. It's hard to plugin without all of my code which I'd prefer to keep offline. The tree tops are split into a 3x3 block grid, each 32x32 piece of the top being it's own block.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems that you are only drawing a single image at each 32x32 square.  So if tree A is in front of tree B, but tree A only partly fills a square, then tree A is the one listed in your `blocks` array and therefore retrieved from your "texture cache"; and not tree B.  So tree A is all that is drawn.

To resolve this, your `blocks` structure would need to be three dimensional - basically, for each 32x32 square, you'd need some kind of "stack" of references to all the images whose corresponding object is found in that square.  Then when you draw that square, draw all of the images in order, from the back to the front.

Comment: Thanks that actually solved my problem. I realized you were right when I looked at my generation and didn't check if one tree overlapped the other, it wasn't a texture issue after all.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.  Good luck with the rest of the game.